# Python. How do I print specific value from json when from similiar names?

Tags: python, json

Okay so my problem is that I need to print out one specific value from a json.
I've managed to print out all the values but not the specific one I want.

The json looks like this:

```
"apple": {
    "stuff": 111,
    "food": [
        {
            "money": 4000,
            "time": 36,
                    },
        {
            "money": 12210,
            "time": 94,
```

It continues like that with money and time.
So my problem is that when I do this:

```
ourResult = js['apple']['food']
for rs in ourResult:
    print rs['time']
```

I receive all the times.. I only want to receive the time under money: 12210 for an example but I don't know how to do that when there is a colon and a value.

I thank you for all the help in advance.

Comment: According to your data, `apple.stuff` is an integer and can't be iterated over. Did you mean to do `ourResult = js['apple']['food']`?

Comment: Yes! Mistyped it in the thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you already know how to get the value of "time", so just do the same with "money" and check it's equal to 12210.

**Edit**

```
for rs in ourResult:
    if rs['money'] == 12210:
        print rs['time']
```

Comment: I know how to get the value of all times, the thing I need is to get the value of time under "money": 12210,.

Comment: So do you know how to use an `if` statement?

Comment: As I'm a total beginner I would not say yes.

Comment: Well, that's a pretty fundamental thing not to know. You should really go and do an introductory tutorial. In the meantime, see my edit.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I've been following tutorials and I'm getting some help from my friend but now I know I need to focus more into the "basics of the basics". Anyways thanks again!